# Performance implications of the NEWSEQUENTIALID() re-sequence on restart

Tags: sql-server

I see a very good case why I should use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` as PK. It would be internal to my system and has [good performance similar to `IDENTITY()` but better than `NEWID()`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32597/Performance-Comparison-Identity-x-NewId-x-NewSeque).

However, [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()` is not sequential after SQL Server restart](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/475131/newsequentialid-is-not-sequential). After restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range, but is still globally unique. So, would It be a bad choice for a primary key - as bad as using normal guids in terms of performance - because of Fragmentation etc?

There is [already a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53617/newsequentialid-resets-sequence-on-server-restart) on this - but can somebody explain this more please.

Comment: Why do you think this is better than an IDENTITY column? What are you trying to accomplish? Forget about the generation costs (negligible or the same) and fragmentation costs (largely eliminated, assuming you don't restart your SQL Server for fun), how about the simple fact that it is four times wider than an INT, meaning you'll get far fewer rows per page, both in the primary table and in any table that contains a foreign key?

Comment: How is your question different than the linked one you mention?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Hmm..I am trying to understand NEWSEQUENCIALID more. It provides the randomness vs IDENTITY() and still sequential with similar performance benefits - also, If one needs to replicate, merge, It's better than Identity - Is that correct. If this is not the case, why would you use NEWSEQUENCIALID() at all? Also - disk space is cheap in many cases, but performance is crucial.

Comment: @AshishGupta - `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`  not `NEWSEQUENCIALID()`

Comment: Well, are you using merge replication now? How likely is it that you will be in the future? And I'm not sure why you think it is "random" - the first one is somewhat random to the casual observer, but every subsequent one is not so random, is it? And again, forget about the cost of generation - "similiar performance benefits" to IDENTITY is like saying my Ford Bronco can go as fast as my Toyota Prius - who cares? Storage and I/O are bigger concerns.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Good points! Thank you. So - does this mean you would use NEWSEQUENTIALID() only when you have merge replication in picture- otherwise use IDENTITY() for less disk space and better I/O?

Comment: Even if I needed to merge data from two systems, I would probably roll my own using identity ranges rather than use merge replication.

Comment: And I also wanted to add - you said `disk space is cheap` but that's only part of the equation. Storage may be cheap but I/O is not, nor is memory. (Well, memory is cheap, but it's also scarce on a busy system.) Your table takes 8000 pages instead of 5000, let's say, when you do a table scan that's 64 MB instead of 40 MB. And when you put that in buffer, that's 64 MB in buffer, not 40 MB. Stop thinking about just disk space.

Comment: Why do you care if it is not sequential after restart? Are you planning to scan this table a lot?